# How can I correctly declare the program id inside a Solana program?

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

I created and tested a Solana contract using Anchor. I am now trying to deploy it on localnet.

When I successfuly run `anchor deploy`, the resulting program id is different than the one declared inside the contract. Any attempt to interact with the contract results with the following error:

```
The declared program id does not match the actual program id
```

I am slightly confused. Judging from the Anchor documentation, I assumed that the program id is deterministic and will match whatever I declare inside the contract. How can I properly declare the program id to get rid of the error above?

Comment: Did you edit the `Anchor.toml` and the `lib.rs` `declare_id!("..."); value` with the pubkey of the keypair created at `target/deploy/<your_program_name>-keypair.json`? You can get the pubkey using `solana-keygen pubkey` command

Comment: @WrathionTBP Maybe I misunderstood something, but doesn't `solana-keygen pubkey` return my own public key, not the program id?

Comment: Yeah but you just had to add the path to the keypair you want to check its pubkey (in this case `solana-keygen pubkey target/deploy/<your_program_name>-keypair.json` assuming the terminal its inside the `anchor init` folder), but you already fixed it.

Comment: @WrathionTBP I see. I mistakenly thought that the program id does not lie on the ed25519 curve so I wasn't sure what the private key inside `target/deploy/<your_program_name>-keypair.json` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding an answer [here](https://github.com/project-serum/anchor/issues/1912).

After running:

1. `anchor build`
2. `anchor keys list`

I was able to get the new string that I used to replace whatever was inside `declare_id!(...)`. I also had to replace it inside Anchor.toml, just under `[programs.localnet]`.

After replacing the strings, I ran `anchor build` once again and I was able to deploy & migrate without any errors.